# How do I delete all left from my cursor in the VS-Code terminal?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In my vs code editor "cmd"+"backspace" leads to deleting all left from my cursor:

```
$ test input 1|
```

would lead to

```
$ |
```

I would like to configure my vs code terminal so that it behaves the same way but can't figure out how to do so.
Currently pressing "cmd"+"backspace" deletes one character left of the cursor.

Comment: It may depend on your shell but try `Ctrl+U` when focussed in the terminal.  Works on bash for example.